# In Illustrator, how to "unflow" text in columns but retain individual page layout

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text-wrap

Hope someone can help. I have designed a template where the text flows into four columns per page, and there are four pages in all.

So in all 16 columns, and the text flows beautifully.

The problem now is that because these 4 pages need to print on front and back of a folded A3 paper.

Much easier to explain visually: 
[image: layouts]

Which means, I need to "unflow" the text from those columns, because Page 4 and Page 1 need to print on one A3 side (because, when folder through the center in landscape, A3's Page 1 and Page 4 will be on the same side), but I cannot easily split the pages and rearrange them as the text is flowing across.

I would love to some idea from experts about how to manage this? I bet this is a common problem in the DTP industry -- the text must flow between pages, but printing wise they need to sometimes be not in sequence?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Well with that much text, I'd have used Indesign from teh start. Can't you simply break the text thread, then re-stack the  rectangles and thread the text again?

Comment: Yup. I usually use indesign if I'm going to have more than 1 page. I suppose you could export the pages as they are, and then rearrange 4th page as the first with Acrobat Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renumber/Rearrange the artboards. You don't need to alter text threads at all.

Or you can save as a PDF, if that's what you are providing the printer, then rearrange the pages in Acrobat.

Seems silly the printer wouldn't do this, unless there's something more you aren't sharing such as artwork which crosses page gutters.